# Bootstrap Carousel in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using the bootstrap carousel in a test site and I cannot get it to run smoothly in Firefox. It runs smooth in Chrome and IE.

The nagging problem is when it transitions/slides to the second image, only a portion of the image displays and then loads. The same thing when it transitions to the third image, only a portion of the image appears to display, and then loads/snaps to regular size.

[Example here](http://www.lestaylordesign.com/test)

Has anyone encountered this in Firefox? (Version 35.0.1)

Comment: works fine on my Safari (MacOs)

Comment: It appears it works fine in IE, Chrome, and Opera. 

I tried reinstalling FF, but no luck.

Comment: I've just checked how it looks on Firefox on MacOs. Works fine, without any problem. Hae you trieed the same Firefox on different PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not the only one. We've seen this across multiple Windows boxes with FF 35.0.1. We've not tried this on a Mac, though. Can confirm this problem exists, and am really glad we're not the only ones who've noticed it. It's a consistent issue, regardless of caching or network speed.

Great news!: It's been fixed in Firefox 36! Try updating your browser. Here's the Bugzilla which should have fixed the problem: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1125077

**[edit]**: Updated Bugzilla URL;

Comment: Having this issue again in Firefox 58.0.2 - viewing - eg - this carousel works without white space on Chrome - but not on Firefox: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp